# remove single quotes from dict values while adding content to yaml file using python ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have an yaml file as mentioned below
test1.yaml

```
resources:
  name:{get_param: vname}
  ssh_keypair: {get_param: ssh_keypair}
```

Now I want to add  test1_routable_net: { get_param: abc_routable_net } under resources of test1.yaml
Here is the code which I tried

```
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
test="{ get_param: abc_routable_net }".strip(‘\’’)
with open('/tmp/test1.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
data['resources'].update({‘test1_routable_net’:test})

yaml.dump(data,file('/tes2.yaml', 'w'))
```

output of above code is 
tes2.yaml

```
resources:
  name:{get_param: vname}
  ssh_keypair: {get_param: ssh_keypair}
  test1_routable_net: '{ get_param: abc_routable_net }'
```

Desired output is
  tes2.yaml

```
resources:
  name:{get_param: vname}
  ssh_keypair: {get_param: ssh_keypair}
  test1_routable_net: { get_param: abc_routable_net }
```

I tried using `test.strip('\'')` , but no use still I see single quotes for the value .... How can I remove those quotes from the value?

Comment: You should update your question to represent actual working code. `ryaml` is not defined anywhere, neither is the variable `test1_routable_net`. And make your input and output files valid YAML: don't make the filename part of your YAML block, I already corrected that once in your other question. Sloppiness in asking questions is a sure sign for sloppiness in programming.

Comment: will try to fix it .... may be I need to go through the ruamel.yaml document for more details .......

Answer (score 2):

In your program `test` is a string. Strings normally don't get quoted when dumped, but if their interpretation would be ambiguous, they will be. That is the reason why your output has the single quotes around them: *to make sure that on reading back in this node is not incorrectly interpreted as a mapping instead of a string*.
Removing the non-existent quotes with `.strip()` therefore doesn't do anything.

You should work backwards from what you what you want to accomplish (you actually want a mapping instead of a string, as one can see from the output).

If you load your desired output, you will see that the value for `test1_routable_net` is a python dict (or a subclass thereof), so make sure that is what you assign to `test`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
test = { 'get_param': 'abc_routable_net' }
with open('./test1.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
data['resources'].update({'test1_routable_net': test})

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Which gives:

```
resources:
  name:{get_param: vname}
  ssh_keypair: {get_param: ssh_keypair}
  test1_routable_net:
    get_param: abc_routable_net
```

This is semantically the same as your desired output, but since you want the `get_param: abc_routable_net` in flow-style, you could add:

```
yaml.default_flow_style=None
```

to get your desired output. You can also look at assigning, to `test`, a `ruamel.comments.CommentedMap`, which gives you more fine grained control over its style (and comments, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

"test" is not a string it is a dict:
example:

```
import ruamel.yaml
import yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
test={ 'get_param': 'abc_routable_net' }
with open('test1.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)

data['resources'].update({'test1_routable_net':test})
yaml.dump(data,open('test2.yaml', 'w'))
```